Connection between Cohen-Lenstra heuristics and related conjectures
The Cohen-Lenstra heuristic is a principle of arithmetic statistics saying that a finite abelian group $G$ should appear "in nature" with probability inversely proportional to $|Aut(G)|$.
In Cohen and Lenstra's original paper (see here for the paper) they discuss this heuristic and related conjectures, especially as it relates to class groups of quadratic number fields.
In particular, my question is regarding the conjectures C4 (for imaginary quadratic) and C8 (for real quadratic). They predict that for $G$ being the odd part of the class group, given $n\in\Bbb{N}$ odd, the average number of elements of order $n$ in $G$ is $1$, respectively $\frac{1}{n}$.
They write in the paper that these two conjectures are "trivial" consequences of the assumptions, together with the work done in the first part of the paper (which is not conjectural). But it is not trivial to me, and I was hoping for help in deducing these two conjectures.
These results seem so natural, so is there a conceptual way of arguing the validity? Or a technical one? Feel free to assume whatever you want, I am only looking for a heuristic argument. I would also be happy with a reference where such an argument is given.
My attempt: Focusing on the imaginary case first: I see that their first assumption (8.1.1) basically allows them to translate averages of (odd part of) imaginary class groups into averages over odd finite abelian groups, in some sense saying that such class groups should behave like random abelian groups. Thus, the heuristic is applicable, but I still don't see how to prove C4, and where the difference in the real and imaginary cases arise.
